# AdoptOpenJDK apt-get update fails with error "Unknown date format Bad header data"

Tags: debian, apt, debian-buster, adoptopenjdk

I am trying to install AdoptOpenJDK Java version 8 with OpenJ9 as the JVM on Debian 10.4. I used [these](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#linux-pkg) instructions to install it. But when i do `sudo apt-get update` to refresh my package list I recieve this error:

```
Err:6 https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb buster Release
  Unknown date format Bad header data [IP: 35.231.52.82 443]
```

This is how my /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like (I removed all commands to make it shorter):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: The repository is currently broken and they are trying to resolve it - see here https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-infrastructure/issues/1399

Comment: I used the workaround descripted in in the issue: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-infrastructure/issues/1399#issuecomment-645924443